# load class only

Tags: java

I have developed eclipse plugin which for any given java project create GUI in form of package structure. I have successfully run my plugin for different java project. 
Now, I thought should try my code in some open source project, therefore, I download JDOM Framework. 
However, I found that the JDOM source code has this structure.

JDOM -> contrib -> src -> java -> org -> jdom2......

where as i assume that the project will have always below structure

Project Name -> Src -> PACKAGE NAME STARTS HERE.....

I load the classes using below code,

```
IPackageFragment[] packages = javaProject.getPackageFragments();
for (IPackageFragment mypackage : packages) {      
  if (mypackage.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_SOURCE) {
        for (ICompilationUnit unit : mypackage.getCompilationUnits()) {
            // unit.getPath().toString() give me path, but how to extract only class name with package
            // save it in to MAP with Package as key
        }
   }
 }
```

Now, I want to show classes with only package name, therefore, I remove first two string (PROJECT NAME, SRC), but this cannot be always the case as for JDOM Framework.

Therefore, how can I get only package name along with class name using my method above? Or should I use different mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the directory structure alone seems to be an awfully error-prone way to go about it. Who knows how deep the directory tree goes? If instead you scan for Java source files, you should be able to construct a reader that finds the package declaration at the beginning of the file. If there isn't one, you don't need to worry about it. Do I need to say you can store package names in a HashSet to avoid duplicate package declarations?

Comment: Not to mention that any Maven- or Gradle-based projects are known to have different structures. Eclipse has "source folders" for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

The `ICompilationUnit` has a `findPrimaryType` method:

```
IType primaryType = unit.findPrimaryType();
```

and `IType` has `getFullyQualifiedName()`:

```
String name = primaryType.getFullyQualifiedName();
```

Comment: greg-449, thank you very much for your answer. It works perfectly but, there is one problem with this approach. If you see original problem, the project structure is JDOM -> contrib -> src -> java -> ,   now, we save our classes but later I also need the remaining structure ie, I need JDOM-> contrib -> src -> java.    How can I get this information. I hope my question clear

Comment: one other thing, for package-info.java, the method  unit.findPrimaryType() returns null. This is for JavaDOC. My question is, can we add any check for these kind of classes?